# Do pgAdmins have graphical E-R diagram?

Tags: pgadmin

I just installed pgAdmin3 and love it every much since it has some cool tools such as graphical query builder. So I wonder if it has graphical E-R diagram tool also?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, no it doesn't.

I'm using [DbVisualizer](http://www.dbvis.com/) to create my ERD.